# how to add dynamic row jquery having dynamic dropdown in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I can add many rows and add event for each text field and add dropdwon dynamically using php successfully at row first.

But I can not duplicate a dynamic dropdown when I click add button also event on dropdown.

Here is Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;


    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        counter++;

        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        cols += "<td><select name='draft_id" + counter + "'><option value=''>Pilih</option></select></td>"; //<select name="draft_id" id="draft_id"></select>
        cols += "<td><input type='text' name='draft_qty" + counter + "' size='3'/></td>";
        cols += "<td><input type='text' name='draft_isi" + counter + "' size='50'/></td>"; //<input type="text" name="draft_isi"/>
        cols += "<td><input type='text' name='harga_satuan" + counter + "' size='8'/></td>"; //<input type="text" name="harga_satuan" id="harga_satuan" />
        cols += "<td><input type='text' name='jumlah" + counter + "' readonly='readonly'/></td>";
        cols += "<td><button type='button' class='deleteRow'>Del</button></td>"; //<button type="button" class="deleteRow">Del</button>
        newRow.append(cols);

        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    });

    $("table.order-list").on("change", 'input', function (event) {
        hitungbaris($(this).closest("tr"));
        hitung();

    });

    $("table.order-list").on("click", "button.deleteRow", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        hitung();

    });

});

function hitung() { //fungsi hitung ini memiliki 2 fungsi sekaligus yaitu ...:
    hitungGrandTotal();
    hitungsisa();
}

function hitungbaris(row) {
    var harga_satuan = +row.find('input[name^="harga_satuan"]').val();
    var draft_qty = +row.find('input[name^="draft_qty"]').val();
    row.find('input[name^="jumlah"]').val((harga_satuan * draft_qty).toFixed(2));
}

function hitungGrandTotal() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $("table.order-list").find('input[name^="jumlah"]').each(function () {
        grandTotal += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("#grandtotal").val(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
}

function hitungsisa() { //bisa juga di gunakan untuk menghitung uang kembali
    //var sisa = "";
    var bayar = parseFloat(document.formpenjualan.bayar.value);
    var grandtotal = parseFloat(document.formpenjualan.grandtotal.value);
    if (bayar < grandtotal){
    //
    sisa = "KREDIT";
    }else{
    //
    sisa = "LUNAS";
    }
    $("#sisa").val(sisa);   
}
```

HTML

```
                    <input type="button" id="addrow" value="Tambah Baris" />        
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"class="order-list table table-striped responsive-utilities jambo_table bulk_action">
                  <thead>
                    <tr class="headings">
                        <th class="column-title"><div align="center">Draft ID </div></th>
                        <th class="column-title"><div align="center">Qty</div></th>
                        <th class="column-title"><div align="center">Uraian</div></th>
                        <th class="column-title"><div align="center">Harga Satuan </div></th>
                        <th class="column-title"><div align="center">Jumlah</div></th>
                        <th class="column-title"><div align="center">Aksi</div></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>

                    <tr>
                        <td>

                                <?php 
                                $result = mysql_query("select * from draft_order");    
                                $jsArrayDO = "var draftID = new Array();\n";
                                ?>
                                <select name="select" onchange="changeValue_draftID(this.value)" class="category-select">
                                  <option>-Pilih-</option>
                                  <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    $jsArrayDO .= "draftID['" . $row['draft_id'] . "'] = {draft_qty:'" . addslashes($row['draft_qty']) . "',draft_isi:'".addslashes($row['draft_isi'])."'};\n";?>
                                  <option value="<?php echo $row['draft_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['draft_id'];?></option>
                                  <?php } ?>
                                </select>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                <?php echo $jsArrayDO; ?> 
                                function changeValue_draftID(id){
                                document.getElementById('draft_qty').value = draftID[id].draft_qty;  
                                document.getElementById('draft_isi').value = draftID[id].draft_isi;  
                                };  
                                </script>

                                </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="draft_qty" id="draft_qty" size="3"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="draft_isi" id="draft_isi" size="50"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="harga_satuan" id="harga_satuan" size="8"/></td>
                        <td align="right"><input type="text" name="jumlah" id="jumlah" readonly="readonly"/></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="deleteRow">Del</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle">Grand Total : </td>
                        <td><input name="grandtotal" type="text" id="grandtotal" readonly="readonly"/></td>
                        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td align="right" valign="middle">Bayar : </td>
                      <td><input name="bayar" type="text" id="bayar" /></td>
                      <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="right"></td>
                      <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td align="right" valign="middle">Sisa : </td>
                      <td><input name="sisa" type="text" id="sisa"readonly="readonly"/></td>
                      <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                </table>
```

you can see the code at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adexs21/zgva37q5/2/)

Please Help me how to clone/add dynamic dropdown using php as row first.

Need Help

Thank You

Comment: Just var a = $("").clone()

Comment: thx for your fast respon...please show me how to create it in JSFIDDLE

Answer (score 0):

using jquery function `.clone()` then insert after `insertAfter()` - *or `appendTo()` the parent DOM element `select.clone().appendTo(select.parent());` [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/cud7kz1z/)* - you can copy/paste the drop down as shown in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/qbwfrwvx/)

```js
var select = $('.test');
$('#btn1').on('click', function () {
 select.clone().insertAfter(select);
});
```

```css
#btn1 {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.test{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">Duplicate</button>
<select class="test">
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
    <option value="5">option 5</option>
</select>
```

---

**Update:**
check this [**PHP Fiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/yg9q-xbvp), it demonstrates something similar to your problem, a dynamically generated drop-down that could be obtained from a database query or JSON response.

However if you want to duplicate the whole set of the text inputs as well as the the dynamically generated drop-down then check this [**PHP Fiddle 2**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/y7hu-8zzh) which shows how to grab the inner html of the container div at first then append additional set of inputs and select.

---

**UPDATE 2:** *Upon a comment*

To give each drop-down list a unique `id`, give the first dynamically generated drop-down an id of use this js code instead:

```
var html = $('#container').html(),
    id = $('.test').first().attr('id');
    id = id.replace(/drop/, '');
$('#btn1').on('click', function () {
    $('#container').append(html);
    id++;
    $('.test').last().attr('id', 'drop' + id);
});
```

As in this [**PHP Fiddle 3**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/1yjx-vh2y), check the console log to see each one's `id`

Comment: Thx Mi-Creativity... I know how to add new row having static dropdown as you see here : cols += "<td><select name='draft_id" + counter + "'><option value=''>Pilih</option></select></td>"; But how to add row having a dynamic dropdown include event to trigger the the text field as first row. The first row i can create dynamic dropdown by passing php array to javasript. But i'm stuck when add second row. Please help again how to create dynamic dropdown as first row using php

Comment: it is the same, just give it some class name and pick it up with jquery depending on that class name, you may need to use `.first()` to pick the very first one

Comment: Thx Mi-Creativity... I'll try as you said, I'm sorry i'm a newbie for scripting. But it's very helpfull if you could modify my jsfiddle.

Comment: wow it's works...thx again Mi-Creativity... But how to trigger the second select  onchange event to fill the input?. when i try your code to clone a row, the select just fills in first row....it doesn't works to fill inputs in second row

Comment: @user3189581, you want that for each drop down fills input fields on its own row with dummy data or what?

Comment: Thx again Mi-Creativity...I will try as you suggested. I think this script var html = $('#container').html(),
    id = $('.test').first().attr('id');
    id = id.replace(/drop/, '');
$('#btn1').on('click', function () {
    $('#container').append(html);
    id++;
    $('.test').last().attr('id', 'drop' + id);
}); will help me